# Screen-scraping JavaScript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web-scraping

I can successfully scrape all the items on [this page](http://www.hm.com/gb/subdepartment/sale) using this script:

```
$html = file_get_contents($list_url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

    if(!empty($html))
    {
        $doc->loadHTML($html);
        libxml_clear_errors(); // remove errors for yucky html
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

        /* FIND LINK TO PRODUCT PAGE */

        $products = array();

        $row = $xpath->query($product_location);

        /* Create an array containing products */
        if ($row->length > 0)
        {            
            foreach ($row as $location)
            {
                $product_urls[] = $product_url_root . $location->getAttribute('href');
            }
        }
        else { echo "product location is wrong<br>";}

        $imgs = $xpath->query($photo_location);

        /* Create an array containing the image links */
        if ($imgs->length > 0)
        {            
            foreach ($imgs as $img)
            {
                $photo_url[] = $photo_url_root . $img->getAttribute('src');
            }
        }
        else { echo "photo location is wrong<br>";}

        $was = $xpath->query($was_price_location);

        /* Create an array containing the was price */
        if ($was->length > 0)
        {
            foreach ($was as $price)
            {
                $stripped = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $price->nodeValue);
                $was_price[] = "&pound;".$stripped;
            }
        }
        else { echo "was price location is wrong<br>";}

        $now = $xpath->query($now_price_location);

        /* Create an array containing the sale price */
        if ($now->length > 0)
        {
            foreach ($now as $price)
            {
                $stripped = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $price->nodeValue);
                $stripped = number_format((float)$stripped, 2, '.', '');
                $now_price[] = "&pound;".$stripped;
            }
        }
        else { echo "now price location is wrong<br>";}

        $result = array();

        /* Create an associative array containing all the above values */
        foreach ($product_urls as $i => $product_url)
        {
            $result[] = array(
                'product_url' => $product_url,
                'shop_name' => $shop_name,
                'photo_url' => $photo_url[$i],
                'was_price' => $was_price[$i],
                'now_price' => $now_price[$i]
            );
        }
    }
```

However, a problem arises if I want to get page two, or if I view 100 per page `file_get_contents($list_url)` will always return page one with its 24 values.

I presume that the page changes are being handled via AJAX request (though I can't find any evidence of this in the source). Is there a way to scrape exactly what I see on the screen?

I've seen talk of PhantomJS in previous answers but I'm not sure it'd be appropriate here given that I'm working in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of a hashtag in the link which is generated by some js script. Turn off javascript for that site and check the output links it generates.

For example for page two it is http://www.hm.com/gb/subdepartment/sale?page=1

Comment: You're an absolute hero.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$file= file_get_html('http://stackoverflow.com/');

// Find your links
foreach($file->find('a') as $youreEement) {
       echo $yourElement->href . '<br>';
}
```